# looping phpmailer

Tags: php

when i send email i get two emails   but it should send email to respective emails.
Lopoping problem ?

```
$array_values = Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => uname1
[1] =>  fullname1
[2] => email 1


)
[1] => Array
(
[0] => uname2
[1] =>  fullname2
[2] => email 2


)
)
$f=0;
foreach($array_values as $mail_vars)
{

//$mail->AddReplyTo($mail_vars[2],'RED');
$mail->AddAddress($mail_vars[2], 'sss');
$body .="<br>";
$body .= 'Username: '. $mail_vars[0];
$body .="<br>";
$body .= 'Password: '.$mail_vars[1];
$body .="<br>";
$mail->SetFrom('email', 'FULLNAME');
$mail->Subject    = "NEW";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
//$mail->Send();

$f++;
}
```

Comment: Please do some basic debugging first. You are referring to a `mail_vars[4]` that doesn't exist at all

Answer (score 40):

Looking through the source of PHP Mailer, you will need to clear the fields. At least the address, maybe more. Here is the section of code from the PHPMailer class that has the clear functions. You are more than welcomed to look through them and try them etc. This is obviously an alternative to re-instantiating a new object, which may or may not cause a memory leak (depending on how many calls you make to it).

So implementing the clearAddresses code:

```
    $mail->Subject    = "NEW";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses(); // should reset the To address and remove the first one from it.
```

I removed the actual code as you just need the description and function name.

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CLASS METHODS, MESSAGE RESET
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /**
   * Clears all recipients assigned in the TO array.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearAddresses() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all recipients assigned in the CC array.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearCCs() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all recipients assigned in the BCC array.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearBCCs() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all recipients assigned in the ReplyTo array.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearReplyTos() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all recipients assigned in the TO, CC and BCC
   * array.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearAllRecipients() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all previously set filesystem, string, and binary
   * attachments.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearAttachments() {
  }

  /**
   * Clears all custom headers.  Returns void.
   * @return void
   */
  public function ClearCustomHeaders() {
  }
```

Comment: Good work, Brad. This is best way to clean up the address rather than recreating the object. This should be the accepted answer..but only one guy upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

if you look through the php mailer code, there is this useful method ClearAllRecipients() if you want to clear to, cc, and bcc all at once.

Answer (score 4):

You need a:

```
$mail=new PHPMailer()
```

in the beginning of your `for` loop -as it is, the second time through it just messes around with the first email (since a new one isn't created).

As you pointed out body also needs to be reset - in fact using a separated var like that isn't very helpful - better to just supply directly to `MsgHTML`.  Since the content of your email is trivial you may also want to send a plain-text version of the data (depends on your target recipient I guess).
So the updated script:

```
foreach($array_values as $mail_vars)
{
  $mail=new PHPMailer();
  $mail->SetFrom('email', 'FULLNAME');
  $mail->AddAddress($mail_vars[2], 'sss');

  $mail->Subject    = "NEW";

  $mail->MsgHTML("<br>\nUsername: ".$mail_vars[0]."<br>\nPassword: ".$mail_vars[1]."<br>");

  //$mail->Send();
  $f++;
}
```

Comment: $body should be reset at the top in the loop

Comment: Yes true - clearly you've got it working enough to have figured that out ;) You really don't need the `$body` var at all {edited}

Comment: If you're sending a password (or any sort of personalised content), you should call `$mail->AltBody = '';` before `$mail->MsgHTML()`, or the text version of your email will contain the first recipient's content.

Comment: This isn't efficient. 1) Creates a PHPMailer object at every iteration. 2) PHPMailer closes the connection to the SMTP when it is destroyed. That means a connection/e-mails. That ain't cheap you know.. Brad's answer provides a more efficient way